# HTML/CSS font color vs span style

Tags: html, css

What should I use?

```
<span style="color:red">test</span>
```

or

```
<font color="red">test</font>
```

and why?

Comment: fist one is actually inline CSS

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You should use `<span>`, because [as specified by the spec](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp), `<font>` has been deprecated and probably won't display as you intend.

Comment: Span (and div) are not deprecated, but they are not semantic either. In other words, they add no "meaning" to the text. They should only be used to group elements without adding meaning: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Span_and_div

Comment: I never said Span or div are deprecated, I find it hard to believe they will ever be deprecated. span was designed exactly for its purpose: to non semantically be able to change certain parts of text.

Comment: I never said span and div are deprecated either and I agree with you that they will probably never be. But it seems reasonable to assume the OP has a meaning with red colored text, for example emphasis. So he ought to use a semantic tag for that. However, if the text just needs to be colored red without semantic meaning (e.g. just to create some colorfulness), then span is a fine choice.

Comment: Aha, I understand. And in that case, your suggestion would be perfect, but as the OP only asked which element to use, `<span>` is preferred out of the two here. :)

Answer (score 33):

Neither. You should separate content and presentation, giving your HTML code logical codes. Think of it this way; to a blind person, or on a browser that cannot display colors, what is left of your code? Why do you want it to be red?

Most probably, your decision to make text red is because you want to give it emphasis. So your HTML code should be:

```
<em>test</em>
```

This way, even non-visual browsers can make sure they give the text emphasis in one way or another.

Next step is to make the text red. But you don't want to add the color code everywhere, much more efficient to just add it once:

```
<style>
  em { color: red; }
</style>
```

This way, *all* emphasized code on your website becomes red, making it more constant.

Answer (score 16):

1st preference external style sheet.

```
<span class="myClass">test</span>
```

css

```
.myClass
{
color:red;
}
```

2nd preference inline style

```
<span style="color:red">test</span>
```

`<font>` as mentioned is deprecated.

Comment: The only suggestion to improve is instead of "myClass" use "redText", or "red".

Answer (score 9):

Use style. The font tag is deprecated ([W3C Wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Html/Elements/font)).

Answer (score 6):

The `<font>` tag has been [deprecated](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp), at least in XHTML. That means that it's use is officially "frowned upon," and there is no guarantee that future browsers will continue to display the text as you intended.

You have to use CSS. Go with the `<span>` tag, or a separate style sheet. According to its [specification](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_span.asp), the `<span>` tag has no semantic meaning and just allows you to change the style of a particular region.

Comment: No, don't target XHTML unless you really know what you're doing: http://www.webdevout.net/articles/beware-of-xhtml. 99.9% of the so-called XHTML out there, is not (valid) XHTML.

Comment: @Peter: Fair enough, I acknowledge that there are multiple valid opinions on the issue. XHTML is just my personal preference. But it's worth pointing out that by "targeting," I meant to imply "writing valid" XML.

Answer (score 6):

```
<span style="color:#ffffff; font-size:18px; line-height:35px; font-family: Calibri;">Our Activities </span>
```

This works for me well:) As it has been already mentioned above "The font tag has been deprecated, at least in XHTML. It always safe to use span tag. font may not give you desire results, at least in my case it didn't.

Comment: Great example; but it does not answer the question: Why?

Comment: @jpaugh, why to use span in place of font tag already been address by other members above. The <font> tag has been deprecated, at least in XHTML. Thank you I will edit my answer.

Comment: Well, that's one way to look at it. I meant, why use *your* solution (regardless of other solutions)? What is unique or beneficial about your example?

Answer (score 4):

Actually I would say the 1st preference would be an external style sheet (External CSS), the 2nd preference would be writing CSS in style tags in the header section of the current page (Internal CSS)

```
<style type="text/css">
<!-- CSS goes here -->
</style>
```

And as a 3rd option - or last resort rather - I'd use CSS in the tags themselves (Inline CSS).

Comment: Agree. Create a CSS class called "red", assign the class "red" to the tag - easy, and good practice.

Comment: Actually... .red wouldn't be a great class name since it's not semantic. .red only describes the look of the class not what it means, .warning or .error would be better.

Comment: Just curious - Is it a bad idea to use inline CSS as a rule?